# ¿Cómo puedo ocultar y mostrar un preload gif despues de un evento click que hace una consulta a una api con c# windows forms?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, async-await

Antes que nada soy nuevo en este lenguaje de programación.

Estoy intentando hacer un login y quiero que cuando el usuario de click al boton pueda ver un preload o spinner para que sepa que se esta procesando la solicitud.

La idea es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

1. El boton debe ocultarse
2. el picturebox debe mostrarse

asi como en esta imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta este punto funciona, pero ya cuando utilizo la consulta de la api y utilizo el async await no funciona se oculta el btn pero no se muestra el spinner y no se si este haciendo bien el proceso y eso hara que se cuelgue.

Código:

```
 public Login(){
    InitializeComponent();
    txtPassword.PasswordChar = '*';

    btnLogin.Visible = false;
    spinnerBtn.Visible = true;
    spinnerBtn.Image = Image.FromFile(@"ruta del gif");
    spinnerBtn.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
 }
```

Función para consulta http

```
public async Task<string> GetHttpUser(string URL){
  WebRequest oRequest = WebRequest.Create(URL);
  WebResponse oResponse = oRequest.GetResponse();
  StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(oResponse.GetResponseStream());

  return await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
}
```

Función evento click

```
private async void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
   string vaidatUser = validateRegisterUsername(txtUsername.Text);
   string vaidatPass = validateRegisterPassword(txtPassword.Text);

   if(vaidatUser == "success" && vaidatPass == "success")
       btnLogin.Visible = false;
       spinnerBtn.Visible = true;

       string URL = $"http://localhost:8000/api/auth/login";
       string respuesta = await GetHttpUser(URL);   //Respuesta 

       btnLogin.Visible = true;
       spinnerBtn.Visible = false;
       Console.WriteLine(respuesta);
   }
}
```

cuando recibo la consulta de la api el boton es el unico que parece que funcionara pero el spinner no se visualiza,
el btn se oculta y se muestra despues del await.

pero creo que es por que se cuelga la app y no se aprecia el spinner es sospecha no se si sea eso, como puedo hacer para optimizar en caso de ser eso o como puedo realizar esta accion de forma correcta ????

no agrego nada relacionado a la api por que no es el problema.

Comment: No estoy tan seguro de que sea posible usar gifs con WinForms. Quizás lo que buscas esté disponible en apps UWP o WPF (son dos cosas diferentes).

Comment: Bueno pues, ya lo solucione, al parecer lo que estoy usando me bloquea la app y eso hace que no se pueda ver el cambio `Visible` de `false` a `true` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Bueno al parecer la "forma" con la que estaba usando para poder consumir una api me estaba bloqueando la app en esos segundos de consulta y por eso no se apreciaba el efecto de spinner.

Remplace :

```
WebRequest oRequest = WebRequest.Create(URL);
WebResponse oResponse = oRequest.GetResponse();
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(oResponse.GetResponseStream());
string await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
Console.WriteLine(sr);
```

Para utilizar `HttpClient`.

```
 HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
 HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(URL);
 response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
 string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
 Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
```

> Soy nuevo en c# recien llevo 2 dias programando en este lengueje, Asi que si las formas, herramientas o tecnologias que estoy usando no son las mas optimas en rendimiento o algo por el estilo me las comentan por favor. Gracias.

Comment: Entendes porque lo primero bloquea y lo segundo no? porque ahi esta el tema...